# Convert video buffer to audio on runtime

Tags: android, ios, audio, video-streaming, avaudioplayer

I am developing an application in which I am required to convert video buffer from a server to an audio on runtime.
Like a video will be on server and it will be fetched by the application in chunks, I want that video chunk to be converted into audio on runtime and play that audio in the mobile audio player.

I am developing an android and ios application. 
Is that possible, any idea or clue of doing it. Any help will be awesome.